# Create a testimonial section in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, testimonials

Im developing a site using drupal 6 and i need a testimonial feature using which users can write testimonials about my site and services. When a users enters a testimonial it has to undergo an approval process and the admin should be able to do this from Drupal's admin control panel. Once approved, it should appear in a page called Testimonials along with the other testimonials. And the admin should be able to remove an approved testimonial if required.

I dont know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether you'd want anonymous users to be able to submit testimonials, one very easy way to achieve this is to set up your testimonial content type to default to unpublished. Then the admin can just go in and set them as published as the approval method.

You would also create a View with a "Page" display that would list your Testimonial nodes, but be sure to include the Published = Yes filter.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Can you help me on the steps involved? Like, how to add a text area for testimonial and how to add a text field for name etc.